# CSS Responsive 3 Column Table

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make a 3 column responsive form with rows that can use merged cells like an html table.

The problem I'm running into is that because of the margin on each column using a width of 30/60/90% doesn't align up with the row above it.

I created an example here (see row 1 and row 3):
https://jsfiddle.net/5ktkxres/2/

```
.formBlock {
    float:left;
    margin: 5px;
    min-width: 200px;
}
.oneFormBlock {
    width: 30%;
}
.twoFormBlock {
    width: 60%;
}
```

I know its a simple fix but I can't find the solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually what you need?

Comment: I want the end of the div on row 3 to align with the div on row 1.. see how its shorter because of the margin...

Comment: I think you need like: https://jsfiddle.net/5ktkxres/3/. for small resolution use media query, for responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or try CSS calc:

```
.formBlock {
    float:left;
    margin: 5px;
    min-width: 200px;
}
.oneFormBlock {
    width: 30%;
}
.twoFormBlock {
    width: calc(60% + 10px);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5ktkxres/10/

Make sure to take into consideration the margin on each side of each input. If you have a threeFormBlock at 90%, you will need to add 20px due to right margin on input one, both margins on input two and left margin on input three.

Comment: Nice, didn't know about calc()

Answer (score 0):

The quickest fix I can see is to change the margin to 1% and then add that to the width of .twoformblock. Like this:

```
.formBlock {
  margin: 5px 1%;
}
.twoFormBlock {
  width: 62%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way is to use Bootstrap for that. (I know it is a "lazy" solution).